# Retrieve if an Updatepanel has made a postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

Can somebody tell me if I can retrieve with JavaScript above the ASP.NET Updatepanel had made a asynchronous postback ?

Thank's for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried registering a startup script in the updatepanel? Something like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.UpdatePanelID, typeof(string), "UpdatePanelScript", "alert('From the UpdatePanel');", true);
```

Here's a link to the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx

Comment: Can you explain it with easy words ? I create an function by the first load of updatepanel and I have to set my own trigger in that ?